# RVM warning message

Tags: ruby, rvm

After RVM installation I get warning message:

> - WARNING: You're using ~/.profile, make sure you load it,
>     add the following line to ~/.bash_profile if it exists
>     otherwise add it to ~/.bash_login:

```
source ~/.profile
```

What does it mean?

Comment: It means that you have a `.profile file` in your home folder, so you should make sure you load it, and add the line that follows to your `bash_profile` file, otherwise add it to your `.bash_login` file.

Comment: But what purpose of adding source ~/.profile at bash_profile? What will be if I don't add this command?

Comment: I test some rvm commands like rvm list known, rvm install and they work well without adding source ~/.profile at bash_profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~/.profile` is used by some distribution vendors (like: debian / ubuntu) for shell configuration like colors and basic configuration, this file is intended for `SH` - minimal shell, when using `Bash` it is loaded as last resort only when `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` is not found.

Because RVM is not compatible with `SH` shell the line to load RVM is not added to `~/.profile` even when no `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` is available, instead `~/.bash_profile` is created.

Now it is up to you if you prefer to move the settings to `~/.bash_profile` or prefer to `source ~/.profile` in there, in some cases you could just remove `~/.profile`.